# How to use GROUP BY in MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I'm using phpMyAdmin for submitting queries. When using GROUP BY in subquery the whole application just hangs without errors until I restart the browser.

I have three tables: `files` stores information about uploaded files, `file_category` defines the available categories for files and `file_category_r` stores relations between files and categories.

I want to count how many files each category has, but some files can have multiple entries in the files table, so I need to group them by `files.filename`.

I tried two different approaches, both resulting in a hang:

```
SELECT 
    fc.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM file_category_r
        WHERE file_category_r.category_id = fc.id 
        AND file_category_r.file_id IN 
            (SELECT f2.id FROM 
                (SELECT * FROM files f3 GROUP BY f3.filename) f2 
                    WHERE f2.mandant_id = 1) 
    ) as file_count 
FROM file_category fc ORDER BY name ASC
```

or

```
SELECT 
    fc.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM file_category_r
        WHERE file_category_r.category_id = fc.id 
        AND file_category_r.file_id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM files WHERE mandant_id = 1 GROUP BY filename) 
    ) as file_count 
FROM file_category fc ORDER BY name ASC
```

I don't see a problem with my queries, running the subquery alone works ok. Even removing the GROUP BY return the result, but the result is wrong, because it's counting duplicate values.

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `opportunity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `calendar_event_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mandant_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `size` float NOT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `filename` text NOT NULL,
  `file` longblob NOT NULL,
  `folder_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_public` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text,
  `file_link` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=104832 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `file_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=445 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `file_category_r` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `file_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=300346 ;
```

What am I doing wrong? The tables are quite big, is it possible the request is too heavy? I'm out of ideas, please help! Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, subqueries in the `SELECT` list tend to be run once-per-row, which is obviously less than ideal in most cases.  If you only have a few rows in `file_category` it's likely not much of a problem, although the usual way around it is to do the subquery as a table-reference that you can join to.  _Why_ do you have the same file multiple times?  Should you be pulling out one or more other cross-reference tables?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! Turns out the problem was, it had to iterate over half-a-billion times for each row with nested subqueries. Joining tables did the trick and got web admin off my back :)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The filenames are the same, but are actually different files, I want them combined in the search results and there is no other reference to map them together. It's all I can work with :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select fc.name, count(*)
from file_category fc
inner join file_category_r fcr on fc.id = fcr.category_id
group by fc.name
```

Not quite sure about that "some files can have multiple entries in the files table, so I need to group them by files.filename", though.
Maybe you need something like

```
select fc.name, count(distinct f.filename)
from file_category fc
inner join file_category_r fcr on fc.id = fcr.category_id
inner join files f on fcr.file_id = f.id
group by fc.name
```

Comment: Thank you! The second one did the trick, with the distinct count on filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Often, the use of `in` can result in inefficient query plans.  You can try `exists` instead:

```
SELECT fc.*, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM file_category_r fcr
         WHERE fcr.category_id = fc.id AND
               exists (select 1 from files f where f.mandant_id = 1 and fcr.file_id = f.id)
        ) as file_count 
FROM file_category fc
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Now, you should add indexes.  Start with `file_category_r(category_id, file_id)` and `files(id, mandant_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use heidisql, not phpmyadmin and your query works fine here. Maybe phpmyadmin has got problems to parse your query.

edit: also, there is a limit for query length. if your "in"-statement is to long, mysql will return an error that phpmyadmin should return.

but if phpmyadmin hangs, i'd try to execute your query my mysqlc or another mysql client like heidisql.

Comment: Yeah, the query was too heavy for phpMyAdmin/webserver to handle while waiting for a result. Using a desktop ui the query worked, but it took a toll on the server performance.